# On what service memory usage depends?

Tags: android

I made a service and, looking at running services, I see that it takes 15MB of memory!
Being it an overall simple service it seems really strange to me and so I wanted to know where to look at, in order to discover why so much memory is taken (note that I'm talking just about service, I made sure to close the activity)

Service's task is to periodically download rss feeds and update an sqllite db if a new article is present. As an internet connection is required service makes use of a network listener too.
These are the attributes:

```
private Timer timer;
private MyDbHelper db;
private NetworkChangesReceiver networkListener; //a broadcast receiver for network state
private NotificationManager notifyManager;
private final NewsServiceB binder = new NewsServiceB();
private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

This is the binder class (in main activity I have a "check now" button, so I need a bindable service):

```
class NewsServiceB extends Binder{
public void downloadRss() throws IOException{
   ... 
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is more of a SuperUser question.

Comment: disagree. It would be a programming question if at least the code of the service is provided. Some usual topics like memory leaks could be discussed with code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a memory analysis tool that shows you what is taking up memory. Take a look at this article from Google about [memory analysis for Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). In particular look closely at the sections on [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Comment: Using tool I detected that problem was in too many useless references: I substituted attributes with locals and memory decreased!